# Using JavaScript to modify form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form with three fields:

- Status
- Department, and
- Delivery Method

I want to display or hide the fields, depending upon whether the user's browser supports JavaScript.

I'm also trying to set one field based upon the value of the other. If `status` is set to **DE**, then I want to set the value of `delivery method` to **DE** as well.

How would I go about implementing this functionality?

Comment: Please post your HTML code for the form

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to do the work for you; it's a service to assist you when you get stuck. I'd start by Googling "JavaScript tutorials".

Comment: Be careful. Java is not the same as Javascript nor is it a subset of it. Your question has nothing to do with Java and shouldn't be tagged as such. In addition you might want to show what you have already tried because this looks like you want to let someone else do your job.

Comment: Understand that you will still need to check whatever data you get from the user for validity. Just because the _status_ is set to one thing doesn't mean the _delivery method_ is guaranteed to be set at you expect. Client side validations and form manipulations are for convenience **only**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't fields you are using created using html  tag? I'm not sure how you can use JAVA to disable them but you can surely use a simple javascript statement.

Say the status field has the id as 'fStatus'.
Then you can simply do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
document.getElementById('fStatus').type = 'hidden'; //to hide it and
document.getElementById('fStatus').type = 'text';   //to un-hide it
</script>
```

Now to execute to execute a function when status changes you will need to modify the html a bit. Like this:

```
<input type="text" id="fStatus" onChange="validate()" />
```

and to execute the same function when the page load, modify body as such:

```
<body onLoad="validate()">
```

The appropriate javascript function would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
  if(document.getElementById('fStatus').value == "DE")
  {
    document.getElementById('fDelivery').value = "DE"; // Assuming that the id of the delivery field is 'fDelivery'
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You may want to do `if( "DE" === document.getElementById('fStatus').value )` - putting the constant first means you'll never accidentally set the value to the constant, and using the triple equals operator (`===`) ensures you're comparing type as well as value, which is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the form if JS is not supported, why not hide it by default and then show it using javascript?

jQuery would make this really easy:

```
jQuery(function() {
  $("form#formID").show();
});
```

jQuery also makes it easy to check the values of form fields:

```
$("input#user_email").val() //=> 'user@email.com'
```

I'd use jQuery if you can ;)

Comment: It is trivially easy to do what he appears to want to do with POJS, too.

Answer (score 1):

Hide it by default with css:

```
#formID {
    display: none;
}
```

Then with js you can display it:

```
document.getElementById('formID').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 1):

The general idea will be to bind an `onchange` event listener to your "status" field:

```
document.getElementById("status").onchange = function() {
    var currentValue = this.value;
    document.getElementById("deliveryMethod").value = currentValue;
}
```

Inside that function, you get the value of the element that has changed with `this.value`. You can then do whatever you like with that value, such as assign it to the `value` of another field.